# Angular 7 bind directive

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have a problem with using directive. When its already imported. Here is the example:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[OnlyNumber]',
})
export class OnlyNumber {

    regexStr = '^[0-9]*$';
    constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

    @Input() OnlyNumber: boolean;

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
        let e = <KeyboardEvent>event;
        if (this.OnlyNumber) {
            if ([46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+A
                (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+C
                (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+V
                (e.keyCode == 86 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: Ctrl+X
                (e.keyCode == 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
                // Allow: home, end, left, right
                (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                // let it happen, don't do anything
                return;
            }
            let ch = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            let regEx = new RegExp(this.regexStr);
            if (regEx.test(ch))
                return;
            else
                e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

And using it with like:

```
 <input
                  type="text"
                  class="form-control"
                  name="amount"
                  id="field_amount"
                  min="1"
                  formControlName="amount"
                  [class.is-invalid]="editForm.get('amount').invalid && (editForm.get('amount').dirty || editForm.get('amount').touched)"
                  [value]="editForm.get('amount').value | numberFormat"
                  OnlyNumber="true"
                />
```

But my directive not working it still getting strings. Any advice ? What i exactly want is when user type something on input it should be accept only numbers not string.

Answer (score 0):

```
OnlyNumber="true"
```

will set the value to a string, use property binding rather than attribute binding.

```
[OnlyNumber]="true"
```

You should not be creating directives like this as it is against accessibility guidelines. Input fields should take all key strokes and provide an easy to understand validation message if the value does not pass validation.

Comment: If 'OnlyNumber' is a directive input, make sure the directive is imported by the current module. ("t').dirty || editForm.get('amount').touched)" [value]="editForm.get('amount').value | numberFormat" [ERROR ->][OnlyNumber]="true"/> <div *ngIf="editForm.get('amount').invalid && (editForm.get('amount').dirty || "): ng:///KhanbankCpmsGrantModule/GrantUpdateComponent.html@0:976

Comment: Make sure you add it to the current module and then add it to the provides section?

Comment: Yes, I added it with shared module. And using it on app module

Comment: If you use the Angular cli to biolerplate you directives this is done for you "ng g d OnlyNumber"

Comment: You need to make sure that the shared module exports it as well as provides it.

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Comment: https://github.com/adriandavidbrand/ngx-ez/blob/master/projects/ngx-ez/src/lib/ez-forms/ez-forms.module.ts this module provied and exports many components and directives.